# Did VS Code 1.14 remove Compare?

Tags: compare, visual-studio-code

I only noticed this because of the project I was working on with a client's CSS file.  I was using Compare in 1.13 to check existing CSS information with some changes I was doing for her.  When I upgraded to 1.14, the Compare function was wonky, allowing me to tag one file for Compare and then not allowing the right-click on the second (or any other) file.  This lead me to believe it was removed, but I didn't see any mention of it in the release notes.

I've since gone back to 1.13.  I rarely use Compare, but in this one instance it alerted me that there may be other issues of which I'm unaware, especially if right-clicking file names in the File Explorer doesn't respond.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue on windows 10 using 1.14.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

The [Compare](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_viewing-diffs) feature was untouched in 1.14, this does not mean, however, that the feature isn't subject to any current bugs related to your platform. On Mac OS X the feature is working as intended.

But as a long time user I've found that the Compare feature has been unintuitive.
I would suggest either using the `Diff` feature (F7 or Shift+F7) or perhaps switching to using `git` and it's diff-ing tool.